# Unedit, remove all edits Video

Tags: youtube, mp4

How do I remove all edits from my video and view the original footage? I have tried and looked up everything
 I have gotten closest with after effect and Adobe Media converter.

Comment: We need more details about how you edited your video originally.

Answer (score 1):

If I have guessed correctly, you uploaded a file to Youtube, edited it using its online editor, and now wish to recover the original file.

If so, you will need to use the [Google Takeout](https://www.google.com/settings/takeout) service. Select only Youtube. There's no way to download just one of your videos.